# Jquery modal with code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem.
side code behind in asp.net I want to run with the modal popup with the following code. But I was not quite successful in my research.

How do you think I should implement a process?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAjaxModal() {
        jQuery('#Modal_Alert').modal('show', { backdrop: 'static' });

    }
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Alert">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblAlertHeader"></asp:Label></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblAlertBody"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
                <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Save changes</button>--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to do

```
if (true)
        {
            //open modal
        }
        else
        {
            //open modal
        }
```

code is running this

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick=" showAjaxModal(); " class="btn btn-default" >Show Me</a>
```

But not work code behind.

```
protected void BtnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //openmodal; }
```

Please help.

Comment: Please share the server side code where are trying to run some js code on the client...

Answer (score 1):

Add this on button click in code behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key", "showAjaxModal()", true);
```

Comment: first html code in masterpage
try your code in user control 
how do it?

Answer (score 1):

### Use the below code it will work

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function showAjaxModal() {
                       jQuery('#Modal_Alert').modal('show', { backdrop: 'static' });
                       return false;

                    }
                </script>
                 <asp:Button ID="BtnKaydet" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return showAjaxModal();" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but;
I wanna code behind 
because run other server side codes and
if (true)
        {
            //open modal
        }
        else
        {
            //open modal
        }

Comment: Hi Turgay ACAR, Kindly use below code                                protected void BtnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenModal", "<script>javascript:showAjaxModal();</script>");
        }